# multiple a href with different colors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I use two or more colors for multiple `a href`?
For example:

```css
    a {color: white;}
    #colorGreen {color: green;}
```

```html
  <div id="navBar">
    <p><a id="colorGreen" href="home.html">home</a><a id="colorGreen" href="page1.html"> page1</a> page2</p>
    </div>

<div id="textDiv">
    <p><a href="link1.html">link1</a></p>
    <p><a href="link2.html">link2</a></p>
    <p><a href="link3.html">link3</a></p>
</div>
```

It only works if the `id="colorGreen"` is given to the `a href` and it does not work if it is given to the `p` that contains all the link and neither to the `div`.

Is there a better way to write this?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css already defines that any `<a>` element will have color white. This means that setting a color on `<p>` will not affect its containing `<a>` elements.

Consider the following:

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="textDiv">
  <p><a href="link1.html">link1</a></p>
</div>
```

Note that although you set `<p>` to use color red, the inner `<a>` element's color will take precedence.

You can override that color by defining a selector with more specificity, like so:

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

p a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="textDiv">
  <p><a href="link1.html">link1</a></p>
</div>
```

In other words, apply the red color to any `<a>` element that is a child of a `<p>` element.

Please review the following resources on [css selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0):

If your link is nested in a `p` tag which has a class or ID like

```
<p id="x1"><a href="#">Some Link</a></p>
```

, you can use this selector to address the a tag:

```
#x1 a:link { color: green; }
```

(i.e `a` tag *inside* an element with ID `x1`)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work when you apply the style to the parent `<p>`, because of the cascading nature of CSS. By design anchor tags (`<a>`) have the `color` CSS attribute populated by the User-Agent Stylesheet, which is like a default stylesheet, stored with your browser's resources. When you apply `color: green` to the anchor's parent, you'll notice that text inside the `<p>`, but not inside the `<a>` will have a green color. While `color` is inherited, it does not override the default styles when inherited, so you will need to apply that directly to your element.

I'm not sure of your use-case but applying styles directly to `id` is not always the best way to go. Maybe try adding a `class` to your `<a>`s that you want to look green. Also consider attribute selectors, in case you want to select an anchor based on what it links to:

```
a[href=home] {
    color: green;
}
```

You can also increase specificity, which will override the default styling of anchors, like this:

```
#colorGreen a {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dániel for your help and explicit info!

I also found out that giving `nav` a color attribute in css and nesting links inside will overwrite any `<a href>` default attribute within.